# Bad state: Stream has already been listened to when using IOWebSocketChannel

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a StreamBuilder that listen to a stream created with the package  **web_socket_channel: ^1.1.0**.

```
Stream getLocationsStream({LatLngBounds latLngBounds, LatLng location}) {
  if (branchMapChannel == null)
    branchMapChannel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(wsEndpointURL("business/branch/maps"));
  return branchMapChannel.stream;
}
```

The StreamBuilder listen to this stream(getLocationsStream()). I am using this Streambuilder inside a custom widget named **Maps()**. When **Maps()** is called in the home page it works fine. But when the **Maps()** is called on another page it shows the following error.

> Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> I/flutter ( 2977): #3      _CompleterStream.listen
> package:async/src/stream_completer.dart:135
> I/flutter ( 2977): #7      _StreamBuilderBaseState._subscribe
> package:flutter/…/widgets/async.dart:137
> I/flutter ( 2977): #8      _StreamBuilderBaseState.initState
> package:flutter/…/widgets/async.dart:111
> I/flutter ( 2977): #9      StatefulElement._firstBuild
> package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4812
> I/flutter ( 2977): #10     ComponentElement.mount
> package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4649
> I/flutter ( 2977): #11     Element.inflateWidget
> package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3615
> I/flutter ( 2977): #12     Element.updateChild
> package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3377
> I/flutter ( 2977): #13     ComponentElement.performRebuild
> package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4700

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue happens because you are trying to subscribe to a `Single Subscription Stream` twice.

If you check the documentation of [IOWebSocketChannel](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/web_socket_channel.io/IOWebSocketChannel-class.html), you can see that:

> stream → Stream 
> The single-subscription stream that emits values from the other endpoint.
> final

#### Suggestion #1:

Instead of directly assigning socket stream to stream builder:

- Create a Socket Utility class (A Singleton or use dependency injection to pass the object around)
- Listen socket events in the Socket Utility class
- In your Socket Utility provide options to add listeners
- Whenever there is a change in stream, notify all the listeners
- In your Maps class use Socket Utility object and set listeners/callbacks

#### Suggestion #2:

Just convert your stream to broadcast stream using: [asBroadcastStream](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/asBroadcastStream.html).

```
Stream getLocationsStream({LatLngBounds latLngBounds, LatLng location}) {
  if (branchMapChannel == null) {
    branchMapChannel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(wsEndpointURL("business/branch/maps"));
    broadCastStream = branchMapChannel.stream.asBroadcastStream();
  }
  return broadCastStream;
}
```

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Yeah, was looking for the documentation. I always prefer the first way, so wrote that first and added asBroadCastStream as second option ;)

Comment: Can you share code for the 1st option. The second option doesn't working

Comment: @AbhijithK Are you storing the stream in a variable or are you just returning it like: `return branchMapChannel.stream.asBroadcastStream();` ? For the first one, I've mentioned the steps there, if you need code I've to write an entire class for you.

Comment: I have tried to return it as broadcast stream but the error is still there. Let me try the first option.

Comment: No, I mean if you return it like: `return branchMapChannel.stream.asBroadcastStream();` the error will be there. You have to store the value of `branchMapChannel.stream.asBroadcastStream();` in a variable and return that variable. As shown in my answer, broadCastStream is a variable with same scope of branchMapChannel